# What is a good and simple software for calculating propeller thrust and required power?

Tags: propeller, performance-calculation, software

My main requirements:

- Calculate propeller thrust with big range of the altitudes (0 - 200 km) or to have air pressure input parameter, which I can type. For example pressure for 152 km is $4.98\times10^{-7} kPa$ as mentioned [here](https://www.avs.org/AVS/files/c7/c7edaedb-95b2-438f-adfb-36de54f87b9e.pdf).
- Calculate required power.
- Calculation can be done for static case, like helicopter which is staying on the ground or moving up very slowly like 1 m/s.

I found [this one](http://www.hoppenbrouwer-home.nl/ikarus/software/propselector.htm) which is good enough for me, but I am not sure if it is doing good calculations for high altitude (50-100km) and I can trust it. Below is the screenshot from it. I would be more confident, if I would be able to type air pressure, but not altitude.

[image: software screenshot]

P.S. I do not want to dispute if it make sense or no to use propeller at high altitudes. I just want to know if there is software which can do this calculation. I will do calculation and based on the calculation will decide if it make sense or not. Please do not put comments about propeller inefficiency at high altitude.

Comment: Propellers are not effective at high altitudes, why do you want to consider it? Might be something you need to use a Matlab or Simulink model for.

Comment: At that altitude the energy equation in Navier-Stokes cannot be decoupled from the momentum equations, which is an assumption commonly made otherwise. In other terms, the speed of sound at that altitude is so low that almost any propeller will be supersonic. So it is unlikely that an off-the-shelf software will suit your needs.

Comment: Do the prop manufacturers have any tools? These are 3 that I am familiar with for small planes: MT-propeller.com, Hartzellprop.com, Mccauley.txtav.com  Are you only interested in helicopter blades?

Comment: Helicopter blades may not be too effective at high altitude, but they have managed to land on Mt Everest, both at the base camp at 18,000 feet and the summit at 29,000 ft. https://qz.com/391598/why-helicopters-havent-evacuated-everyone-from-mount-everest-yet/

Comment: @AEheresupportsMonica On high altitude it will be supersonic, but air density is low and maybe it is not bad, that propeller is supersonic. Actually, I do not want to dispute if it make sense or not. I just want to know if there is software which can do this.

Comment: @CrossRoads Yes, I am interested only in helicopters. Like something vertically going up very slowly or hanging at the same altitude with the propeller usage.

Comment: I am not disputing whether it is good or bad, that is obvious, I am just saying that this is vastly out of the scope of typical propeller design software. None of the propeller programs I have worked with deal with high mach numbers reliably.

Comment: Actually, it is [even weirder](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=speed+of+sound+at+152km+altitude). TIL that the speed of sound mostly increases in the ionosphere beyond 100km.

Comment: @AEheresupportsMonica ok, thank. I understand.